# DraftJs - update editer state with new content state using Modifier.removeInlineStyle()

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a function for setting font size inline style. It works mostly, except after cycling through several font-sizes, i have to toggle the button twice. So to try to solve this, I want to cycle through the current selction's content state, remove all the current font size styles, and then toggle the new style. This is what I have so far, except `Modifier.removeInlineStyle()` does not seem to be being applied and I am still left with my original issue.

state is set:

```
constructor(props: RichTextEditorComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.propsToState(props);
}

propsToState(props: RichTextEditorComponentProps) {
    return {
        editorState: props.content ? EditorState.createWithContent(
            ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
                convertFromHTML(props.content).contentBlocks,
                convertFromHTML(props.content).entityMap
            )
        ) : EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
}
```

method in class:

```
onFontSizeStyleClick(fontStyle: string) {
    const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const styles = this.state.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle();
    const selection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
    Object.keys(FontStyleMap).forEach(style => {
        if (styles.has(style)) {
            Modifier.removeInlineStyle(contentState, selection, style);
        }
    });
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, fontStyle));
}
```

an then this get called from:

```
<button
    type="button"
    className="style-button"
    onClick={() => this.onFontSizeStyleClick('fontSizeXS')}>
    SM
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    className="style-button"
    onClick={() => this.onFontSizeStyleClick('fontSizeNormal')}>
    N
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    className="style-button"
    onClick={() => this.onFontSizeStyleClick('fontSizeL')}>
    L
</button>
<button
    type="button"
    className="style-button"
    onClick={() => this.onFontSizeStyleClick('fontSizeXL')}>
    XL
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to call my onChange method with EditorState.push as the argument:

```
onFontSizeStyleClick(fontStyle: string) {
    let contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const styles = this.state.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle();
    const selection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
    Object.keys(FontStyleMap).forEach(style => {
        if (styles.has(style)) {
            contentState = Modifier.removeInlineStyle(contentState, selection, style);
        }
    });
    contentState = Modifier.applyInlineStyle(contentState, selection, fontStyle);
    this.onChange(EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, contentState, 'change-inline-style'));
}
```